# Did any Antarctic expeditions use coal?

Tags: antarctica

During the ["Heroic Age" of Antarctic exploration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroic_Age_of_Antarctic_Exploration) (roughly 1890 to 1920), did any expeditions use coal as a fuel or heat source?  I'm not just asking what they carried while walking in the interior, I'm interested in what they used at their stationary encampments on the coast as well.

Comparing the success and failure of different expeditions, methods of transportation and keeping warm are believed to have made quite a difference.

Comment: Given that liquid fuels are better in all respects (more efficient, easier to use &) one can hardly imagine anyone using coal instead of kerosene.

Comment: Have you ever tried carrying coal? British explorers used "petrol" which was kerosene not today's usage of gasoline. They did use coal in the semi-permanent camps on the coast where they just had to unload it from their ships.

Comment: @TheMathemagician, so they used kerosene out in the field and coal at their coastal camps?  If you had a source, that would be a great answer.  (And yes, I've carried coal.  Grew up shoveling coal to keep our house warm.)

Comment: Roland Huntford's "The Last Place on Earth" is excellent.